# SQL query to get the author who having maximum number of post (custom post type) in Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I would like to get the author information based on a particular criteria. The criteria is that, would like to get the author who having maximum number of post(custom post type).

This is the code I am trying to get the result.

```
$author_query = new WP_User_Query(array ( 
                           'orderby' => 'post_count', 
                           'order' => 'DESC', 
                ));

$authors = $author_query->get_results();

foreach ( $authors as $author ) {
    echo $author->ID;
    echo $author->display_name;
}
```

Comment: This should be correct according to the documentation. What are you getting now thats not correct?

Comment: The above code will give the post count of post. Here I have custom post type instead of default post. I would like to get the result based on my custom post type's post count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using custom sql query. Posting the answer for others who need it in the future.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.ID,post_count  FROM wp_users RIGHT JOIN (SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) as post_count FROM wp_posts WHERE ( ( post_type = 'custom-post-type' AND ( post_status = 'publish'  ) ) ) GROUP BY post_author) p ON (wp_users.ID = p.post_author) WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY post_count DESC
```